# Form days value change with respect to the month

Tags: javascript, forms

How can I create a day drop-down that shows the correct number of days depending on the  Month selected in other drop-down?

I dont want the user to enter a date of birth.

Can this be done with any built in functions in the Javascript or Php Dynamically?

Or do I have to write separate functions for each month?

Comment: I took the liberty of rephrasing parts to make clearer what you want. If it's not what you intended, feel free to roll back

Comment: try http://www.datejs.com/ it's great

Comment: Personally I LOATHE dropdowns for something as simple as entering a dat number - why not just have simple text field and validate the number the user enters?

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there are no built-in Javascript or PHP functions to dynamically manipulate an HTML "day in month" dropdown.

However, there are date functions in both languages ([PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php) · [Javascript](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Javascript_Dates-The_Complete_Reference)) that can tell you how many days are in a given month.

I recommend using Javascript to [manipulate](http://www.mredkj.com/tutorials/tutorial005.html) the children of your "day" `<select />` element [accordingly](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Javascript_Dates-The_Complete_Reference#quickIDX7), when there is a change in selection in your "month" `<select />` element.

Or save yourself the trouble and use the [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) library.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

1 to 28 are common for all months.
for 29 onwards we have to make choice.

787:

```
addOption 29 when feb and leapyear
addOptions 29 30 when month with 30 days april,june,sep,nov
addOptions 29 30 31 when months with 31 days   jan,march,may,july,aug,oct,dec
```

if clicked second time remove all added options and then re check the month and year value to find the category in which the month lies GOTO 787

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var monthselected,yearselected,mtype=0,visited=0;

        function removeOptions(){  //removes options call each time the day selector is clicked 
        var x=document.getElementById('dayselect');
        while(x.length>29)
            { x.remove(x.length-1);}
            }

        function addOptions(mtype)
        {                              //adds options acc to mtype
        //alert('initialising');
        var i;
        var x=document.getElementById("dayselect");
        for(i=29;i<=mtype;i++)
        {   var option=document.createElement("option");

        option.text=i;
        try
          {//alert('trying');
          // for IE earlier than version 8
          x.add(option,x.options[null]);
          }
        catch (e)
          {//alert('catching');
          x.add(option,null);
          }
        }
        }                           
        function isleapyear(year){ //find if year is leap or not
                if((year%4)==0)
                {
                if((year%100)!=0)
                {
                return true;
                }
                else return false;
                }
                if((year%400)==0)
                    {

                    return true;

                    }

        else return false;
        }                   




        </script>




<html><td id="bday" >Birthday</td>
<td><select  id="month" name="month" class="int" onBlur="monthselected=document.getElementById('month').value;">
                            <option value="00">Month</option>
                            <option value="01" >January</option>
                            <option value="02" >  February</option>
                            <option value="03" >  March</option>
                            <option value="04" >  April</option>
                            <option value="05" >  May</option>
                            <option value="06" >  June</option>
                            <option value="07" >  July</option>
                            <option value="08" >  August</option>
                            <option value="09" >  September</option>
                            <option value="10" >  October</option>
                            <option value="11" >  November</option>
                            <option value="12" >  December</option>
                            </select>

    <label id="year-label" class="year int">Year<select class="int" id="year" name="year" selected= onBlur="yearselected=document.getElementById('year').value;"><option value="0" >YYYY</option>
   <?php for($i=2012;$i>1912;$i--){echo "<option value=\"$i\">$i</option>";} ?>
                                                                                </select>

 <label id="day-label" class="day int">Day<select id="dayselect" class="int" name="day" onClick=
"if(monthselected==4||monthselected==6||monthselected==9||monthselected==11)
                                {mtype=30;}
                            if(monthselected==2&&isleapyear(yearselected))
                                {mtype=29;}
                            if(monthselected==2&&!isleapyear(yearselected))
                                {mtype=28;}

else if(mtype==0){mtype=31;} 

if(visited!=0){removeOptions();}
   addOptions(mtype);
   visited=1;">
 <option value="0" >  DD</option><?php for($i=1;$i<29;$i++){
                        echo "<option value=\"$i\">$i</option>";} ?>
  </select>

   </label>


   </td>
```

this is what i was working on today.
the appropriate nodes are being added or removed on onClick event.

Comment: there is some bug in this sometimes the change does not happen as needed